# Use magento CMS block code in template files

Tags: php, magento, templates, magento-1.7

This is the first time I am creating a custom tempalte for Magento. I installed a 3rd party plugin, that allows me to use this code in the cms editor:

{{block type='bannerslider/bannerslider' template='bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml'}}

Now, I want to use this on a page in my template. What php code should I use to get this to work ?

I tried

```
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bannerslider/bannerslider') ?>
```

But that displays nothing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare your block inside layout file of your custom template (usually, `local.xml`) under some handle (like `default` or `catalog_product_view`).

For example:

```
<block type="bannerslider/bannerslider" name="banner_home" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml"/>
```

under `<default>` handle would let you to call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('banner_home') ?>` in any place of your template. Notice that you have to use name from layout, not block class to call it with `getChildHtml`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative I received from someone else:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bannerslider/bannerslider')->setTemplate('bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```